# Rebuild pki directory and associated changes

Tags: fedora, ssl, certificates

Let me preface this with, "I am not looking for a free lunch."

I royally screwed up my cert storage recently and during my attempt to repair I made things worse.

I am looking for a thorough explanation of how SSL pem and crt files work in tandem with Fedora (or similar pki/tls structure). **A link to a lengthy, thorough explanation of how certs are stored and organized** is welcomed and will be accepted in lieu of manually typing out an answer. I have found snippets of clues here and there, but I am really looking for what cert management workflow looks like, why and when it should be engaged in, and such. the generation of certs is beyond the scope of the question, rather focus on the management and organization of.

My goal is to completely remove all certs from the system, then piece meal reintroduce them. yum/dnf is not available due to this process, however, `curl --insecure` to well known ca-bundles etc.. are acceptable for this exercise.